# Spotify-Play songs using custom play list from Spotify media player

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, spotify

I am developing some kind of Spotify and Instagram Combo application on **native android(kotlin)**. I have integrated **Spotify SDK** into my application and as per **SDK'S** scenario my all songs from the application will be played in the Spotify media player. However, I have created an inner player that receives progress from **Spotify** player and update accordingly such as seekbar, play/pause buttons. I am facing a problem here which I am unable to solve. **Following is my problem scenario.**
The problem is that when my application is running properly in the background then the player plays the songs from the play list created in the application in the loop because I have handled all the inner media player callbacks such as ****play/pause**, **next/previous**** buttons to play according to my play list but I am unable to handle **Spotify Media Player** play/pause and next, previous buttons on which our core songs playing scenario is depend. Because if the application is removed from the background then the songs will be played according to Spotify media player and that media player will play songs according to Spotify application and here our application suffers because we also cannot play songs according to play list created in the application by clicking on **next, previous** buttons of the Spotify media player.
So I need a solution to handle the **callbacks** of **Spotify** Media player **next, previous** buttons or is there any way to push **custom play list** from my application to **Spotify media player** so that even if my application is removed from the background our songs always played according to provided play list.